# Reporting if Performance Insights is enabled using the aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

aws pi help displays two options, describe-dimension-keys and get-resource-metrics however, does anyone know of a means by which one can report if Performance insights is actually enabled on your RDS databases using the aws cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) for that.

Example:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances \
    --db-instance-identifier database-1 \
    --query 'DBInstances[0].PerformanceInsightsEnabled' \
    --output text
```

Example output:

```
True
```

Comment: Perfect. I have made an addition and with your help, this gives me what I needed. aws rds describe-db-instances --output table --query 'DBInstances[*].[Engine,DBInstanceIdentifier,PerformanceInsightsEnabled]'

Comment: @Scouse_Bob Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out:-)